# Windows registry has hundreds of near duplicate entries

Tags: windows-registry

I was perusing my registry today (Windows 10 Pro x64) and noticed hundreds of near duplicate keys.

The keys have the same name with the near dupe appending a `.1` or `.2`. Within the keys the `CLSID` values are identical. The bare key with no numberic suffix has an additional `CurVer` entry, but it just points to the highest numbered suffix key.

[image: image showing key just point to its own duplicate CLSID]

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Video_TVServer.VideoImageSettings]
@="VideoImageSettings Class"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Video_TVServer.VideoImageSettings\CLSID]
@="{EF884939-F1EA-4EFB-B676-D2F802177C5F}"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Video_TVServer.VideoImageSettings\CurVer]
@="Video_TVServer.VideoQualitySetting.1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Video_TVServer.VideoQualitySetting.1]
@="VideoImageSettings Class"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Video_TVServer.VideoQualitySetting.1\CLSID]
@="{EF884939-F1EA-4EFB-B676-D2F802177C5F}"
```

Any idea how to track down what program causes these? <s>and how to clean them out?</s>

Comment: Commentary is designed to be temporary.  I have deleted the rest of my comments since they were not longer helpful and were determined not to be necessary.

Comment: @Ramhound I agree. I routinely delete my comments after they have served their purpose. However me deleting my comments is **entirely** different from someone else removing them, and removing them silently to boot.

Comment: The comments you speak of were flagged as no longer being necessary to answer your question.  In this case they served their purpose.  If you feel helpful information was contained within those deleted comments, you should include the information, in the question body.  *From what I recall, the deleted comments were just saying I was wrong, and I had failed to to read your question.*

Answer (score 2):

This is normal, and you shouldn't touch things in the Registry unless you are ABSOLUTELY CERTAIN you know EXACTLY what you are doing.

Windows and installed applications can create any registry keys they deem necessary for their function. There's nothing uncommon or unexpected about what you have described here.

Manually "cleaning" has a significant chance of causing serious problems, and so you shouldn't do it.

On a related note, just about ANY program that claims to be able to repair problems with your computer by cleaning the registry is lying. Flat out lying.

Update for the change to what was asked: determining which application wrote a registry requires sleuthing and is not an exact science. If the application documentation states the registry keys it creates, great, but the vast majority don't. Other methods involve searching for what appear to be the unique but consistent portions of the key names. In this case I'd look for references online to TVserver, or I'd look for other keys in the registry with that same term and see if one references a specific application.

Because there is no guarantee whether either of these, or other, methods will result in any concrete data, there is no consistent method to determine which applications place keys unless, as I've already stated, they tell you they did it.

But to reiterate: "registry cleaning" should not be done. I don't care if you've been doing it for decades: registry cleaning has not been a legitimate part of any computer fixes for more than a decade now.

There are times when an application is removed and doesn't clean up after itself: it doesn't matter, keys bring left behind do not break anything or slow your computer down in any meaningful way.

The situation ONLY changes when you are attempting to fix an application and must manually remove it because of other failures, and in these cases you aren't trying to identify random, unrelated keys, you are trying to find the keys that belong to an already-known program, a significant and key difference, and often a much easier process.

Because you have not given us an error you're trying to fix and you havs specifically asked about how to go about things the wrong-way-round, starting with unidentified registry keys and trying to find the application that might have dropped them, the best assumption is that you aren't dealing with that situation and therefore shouldn't be manipulating your registry.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the classes as referenced by the GUID (like `{EF884939-F1EA-4EFB-B676-D2F802177C5F}`) under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID`. Inside, you may or may not find the `InprocServer32` key which refers to the DLL (or .NET assembly or otherwise) that actually provides this COM/ActiveX object.

The entries in the question were created by the NVIDIA display driver.

Don’t remove them. It’s just how COM works.